# Extract ASP image from URL

Tags: asp.net, html, extract, wget

I am struggling to extract images from a website which are given as ASP scripts in the form

```
<img src="/Watermark/displayImage.asp?id={%SOME_ID%}">
```

I am used to extract images with `wget` and the resource path which works fine for standard JPG or PNG files. However, if I try to do the same thing with the ASP file I just get an unreadable binary. Does it really need to be processed by the Browser's render engine or is there any command line tool or library which helps me extracting the image?

Due to the huge number of images it is absolutely necessary to do it automated. If not possible otherwise I would try to do it through the GUI of the browser with a framework like Selenium. However, this would be a poor and horrible performing solution and I would welcome any solution which does not require a Browser.

Comment: what does this binary look like?

Comment: I think it is mostly image information. A quick hexdump did not reveal any longer coherent ASCII characters.

Comment: What happens if you put the resource path directly in the browser? What do you get?

Comment: The browser cannot render it, displays garbage characters starting with for example `BM6P6(Ð@ ÄÄÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿÿ`.

Comment: It works though if I download the binary, include it in a local html file inside an image tag ` <img src="img.asp">` and open the file in the browser.